# Firebase Analytics first_open from Google Analytics

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

My Android app right now uses Google Analytics.

However, I want to add Firebase Analytics as well.

Let's say the new version of the app now has FA.

1. Will the 'first_open' event be triggered for old users and mark them as they've first opened the app only now?
2. Is there any possibility to link FA with GA and get the correct 'first_open' for the old users?
3. Should I introduce my own 'user property' to mark users that had a previous version of the app when they first run the new version?
4. Maybe a tricky question: If a user installs the new version, and FA attempts to set such 'user property' (only once ever), but the user doesn't have an Internet connection at this moment. Will this 'user property' be sent to FA somehow in the future?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current Firebase Analytics library will report first_open when an app  with Firebase Analytics is first launched. This includes launch after the app is update from version w/o Firebase to version with Firebase. We are working on excluding first_open from users after update to app with Firebase but this change is not in yet.

FA is not aware of GA in the app and there is no way to tell FA if this is first_open after upgrade vs first_open after app install. This will be automated in one of the next releases as I mentioned earlier.

Setting user property will not work as first_open is recorded early in the app life cycle and before you can get access to FA singleton. You will not have a chance to set the user property before first_open event is recorded.

Setting user property is orthogonal to the app connectivity. All events logged before the property was set will not have it, all event logged after the property is set will have the property set. Connectivity only impacts when the data can be uploaded, not the content of the data. If your app is running on device that is offline the data will be uploaded when the device gains connectivity. The data itself is almost identical.

Comment: Oh @djabi, Thank you very much for your help and explanations! It was eye-openning to understand that user properties are properties of the future events. Firebase is amazing! :)