# Difference between firebase first_open event count and fabric new user

Tags: firebase, google-fabric

I have completely different numbers in firebase `first_open` event count and fabric new user. `first_open` number is about half of new users in Fabric. I've already read [How event "first_open" in firebase analytic count?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38331910/2329085) and it is not my case.
The only case I guess is problem in reporting firebase event? Is anybody thinking about another reason?

Comment: Is this on Android and iOS or just one of the two? Thanks! :)

Comment: This is on Android platform @ToddBurner .

Comment: happens with me as well, don't know why it happens?