# When first_open event in Firebase is logged?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am confused with `first_open` event in Firebase.
Here is the document :
[Document](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en)

> first_open:   the first time a user launches an app after installing or
>   re-installing it.
>
> This event is not triggered when a user downloads the app onto a
>   device, but instead when he or she first uses it. To see raw download
>   numbers, look in Google Play Developer Console or in iTunesConnect.

However some people from Google said that : 
[Refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38332408/951917)

> The last important distinction is that when existing users migrate to
>   the new version of your app which includes Firebase, they will log a
>   first_open event. And so, even though they are not new users, they log
>   a first_open.

As my understanding, If we update app by Google Play then start app again first_open will be logged ?  Is that correct ?

**Update** :
Firebase version
root/

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
```

app/

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.3'
```

Comment: Please provide links to where you got these quotes from.

Comment: I think you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331910/how-event-first-open-in-firebase-analytic-count

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
Here is the link from google people : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38332408/951917

Comment: @miho39 Ohh, What a coincidence. Both link are same. :D

Comment: @PratikButani : Unbelievable :D
Btw, have you know about this ?

Comment: You can check my answer. @miho39

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have just updated link in description . Can you have look at it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188388/discussion-between-miho39-and-pratik-butani).

Answer (score 2):

### [first_open](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en)

> the first time a user launches an app after installing or
> re-installing it.
>
> This event is not triggered when a user downloads the app onto a
> device, but instead when he or she first uses it. To see raw download
> numbers, look in Google Play Developer Console or in iTunesConnect.

So I think,

It will not count again if you are updating your app. It will just count when you launch your app first time after **installing** or **re-installing.**

Comment: @Partik : Thanks for reply. Yes, I agree with you because it's a document ! However 

Steve Ganem is a Product manager from Google and he said that it still counts and they will fix in next version ??? ( is that a bug or something like that )

Comment: May be that is not bug but they have changed policies. Do not know much more about that.

Comment: Yeah, so we want to know when did they change or in which Firebase version was fixed ( I guess it's still counted )