# How is a first_open event logged?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

In our Firebase reporting, we have first_open events and User_SignUp.

I am wondering - is first_open collected when someone launches the app without being signed in? As in a first_open is registered as you launch the app, before you log in or register?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't know anything about when the user signs in.  It only tracks general activity, or whatever you choose to track with events you create.

There is a lot of information out there about first_open if you do a search.  The events you add on top of that are not relevant to the way it works.

- [How event "first_open" in firebase analytic count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331910/how-event-first-open-in-firebase-analytic-count)
- [When first_open event in Firebase is logged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681982/when-first-open-event-in-firebase-is-logged)
- https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?hl=en&visit_id=638191804939006352-476090075&rd=1
- https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/AIcjbXNxBLY

It seems to me that it's impossible for any custom event to ever fire before first_open.

Comment: Thanks Doug. 

"This event is not triggered when a user downloads the app onto a device, but instead when he or she first uses it".

So I download and and open. I am now on the sign up/login screen & this is counted as a first_open.

Will I be counted as a "new user" (equal to "first_open), even though I have not signed up?

Is it the case that someone who downloads and opens the app is assigned a user ID and counts as a new user, even if they have not created an account?

A "new user" is surely someone who has signed up to the app and is now active on it in some way.

Comment: "Firebase doesn't know anything about when the user signs in." Whatever it records happens independently of you how make them sign in to your app, or not.

Comment: Right, it's confusing and misleading though for Firebase to equate first opens with new users, right? As in I can log in and see 100 new users but really these are just people who have downloaded and opened the app and that's it!

Comment: "Users" to me are active users, not just people who have downloaded and installed. I get why it is a metric though and it does give you insights.

Comment: Does it equate the two?  How are you receiving that information?  The definition of first_open is pretty clear on its own terms, regardless of what you're doing for authentication.  If you want to measure the effect of your own auth, then that's something you'll have to measure separately.  If that is not working the way you expect, then maybe reach out to Firebase support.